# Preg_replace and iso-8859-1 chars matching

Tags: php, regex, iso-8859-1

I have a problem with the preg_replace function.

In my code i will use it to delete all chars that are not letters or numbers at the beginning of a string.

This works well, but when the $string contains iso-8859-1 character like " è, ò, à, ù, é, ì " there are considered not words, and all were removed.

```
preg_replace('/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '', $string);
```

ie. If `$string` contains `èxample` the output will be `xample`.

I need that these iso-8859-1 vowels are included.

Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: "ISO characters" doesn't make that much sense; if the string was encoded in ISO-8859 it could not contain any "other" characters, hence cleaning it would be unnecessary. Do you mean *all characters encodable in ISO-8859-1*? Or is that simply your way of saying "some characters with accents"? If the former: the laziest way would be a round-trip conversion to ISO-8859-1 to discard all characters not representable in that encoding. If the latter, specify the exact set of character you want to keep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCRE does not support Unicode blocks (in which case things would be much easier), so you really have no option other than to specify the set of allowed characters (or its negation) manually. The regex would look like

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\xC0-\xFF]+
```

The problem is that the range `\xC0-\xFF` also includes undesirable characters (e.g. the division sign, `\xF7`), so you have to break it down into acceptable subranges depending on your requirements. Look at the [codepage layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout) to help decide which characters are OK and which are not.

Comment: Perfect solution. Define the ranges is perfect.

Comment: preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\xFF]+/i', '', $str); with this ignore-case regexp, you also exclude division(D7) and moltiplication(F7).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$string = "1èxample";
$r = preg_replace('/^[^\p{L}\p{Nd}]+/', '', $string);

echo $r;
```

tested on http://writecodeonline.com/php/

output

> 1èxample

`\p{L}` is any letter in any language. So this matches any letters.

`\p{Nd}` is any digit in any language.

See [Unicode Character Properties on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) for more details.

Comment: "Any letter in any language" - so Cyrillic too? Hebrew? Korean? Is that what the OP wants?

Comment: Yes matches Cyrillic letters, too. And Japanese, Chinese, .... I don't know, if that is what the OP wants, thats my assumption.

Comment: @stema: The OP is specifically interested in ISO-8859-1, so this seems to be too liberal.

Comment: @Jon Does it really hurt to use Unicode properties to find letters? If the OP has some ISO-8859-1 encoded data, it can only find the letters that are there, no Cyrillic or Japanese ones, they can't be in the source data. It is much more readable, than using some range, where I need the codepage to see what they are matching. (I am not a php expert, so I don't know what php is doing internally with strings, maybe there can go something wrong when Unicode properties are used on non-unicode strings !?.)

Comment: @stema: Well, for one you 'd need to add the [`/u` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) for this to work. That modifier assumes that both pattern and subject are UTF-8, so you 'd need to convert first (it would fail hard on ISO-8859-1 input). Finally, it would be a lot slower. Other than these it would work fine.